# I'd like to know the name and a few details of a certain time-keeping structure in the human brain

Tags: human-biology, brain

I once heard of this structure on the Discovery Science channel and have since forgotten the name. The details I remember about it were that it is the central time-keeping device for the brain located in the geographic center of the human brain. The DSC only mentioned it in passing to describe a person with an abnormality in this structure. Can someone post some reliable research links and a short description of it? I don't trust google much and am not good at using it, so thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are probably referring to the [suprachiasmatic nucleus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suprachiasmatic_nucleus).

Note that, although this is the central clock, there are also so-called "peripheral clocks", for instance in the liver, pituitary and other organs that can finely tune rhythms in the organism.

You may also want to have a look at the Wikipedia page for [circadian clock](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circadian_clock) and references therein.

Comment: okay thank you very much, that looks like what i was referring to. I also heard it was very very small, and the wikipedia article said 20k neurons and the size of a grain of rice. I'll remember circadian clock too!

Comment: Suprachiasmatic Nucleus is a part of Hypothalamus, which might be an interesting read as well - hypothalamus is very important